# Why do I get "TypeError: a.lng is not a function" in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Also I don't know where to look. The Google Maps API version is 2.

Edit: The file is http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/tr_ALL/mapfiles/400d/maps2.api/main.js line 610
Edit: I thought that the version 3 but it is 2.

Comment: Some context would probably help.

Comment: 1. The error is in your code, not the API code, so we need a link to a map that exhibits the problem or a jsfiddle that does.  2. that file is from the v2 API (therefore you are using v2 not v3).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by

```
map.addControl((new GSmallMapControl()));
map.addControl((new GMapTypeControl()));
map.setCenter((new GLatLng(38.92220023349402, 35.5), 6));
```

The correct code should be:

```
map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(38.92220023349402, 35.5), 6);
```

Comment: That code is Google Maps API v2 code (your question is not correct).  Note that v2 of the Google Maps API has been deprecated and may stop working as early as May 2013, so new maps should be developed in v3.